# How can I write factories for Models that validate each other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

Parent Class:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :kids
  validates_presence_of :kids
end
```

Kid Class:

```
class Kid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, inverse_of: :kids
  validates :parent, presence: true
end
```

Parent Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :parent do
    2.times do
      parent.kids << FactoryGirl.create(:kid)
    end
  end
end
```

Kid Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :kid do
    parent
  end
end
```

This configuration causes an infinite loop. I've tried every combination of FactoryGirl.build, FactoryGirl.create, after(:build), before(:create), associations, building second dummy factories, etc.

What is the best way to write these factories? Have I made a silly mistake?

Seems like others have experienced this issue as well: http://www.rubyfocus.biz/blog/2010/12/18/factory_girl_association_hierarchies_inverse_of.html

Ruby 2.2.1, Rails 4.1.5, rspec-rails 3.0.2, factory_girl_rails 4.4.1.

Comment: Validating presence at creation time is almost always not what you want because it forces artificial constraints on the UI and controller. Add a validated_at field and do the presence checks conditioned on it being set http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation. Then FactoryGirl won't have this problem.

Comment: Thanks @Gene, but this dual-validation pattern is actually ideal for my use case (it's mainly non-UI logic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my use case, this worked:

Parent Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :parent do
    2.times do
      parent.kids << FactoryGirl.create(:kid)
    end
  end
end
```

Kid Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :kid do
    parent {Owner.new}
  end
end
```

This pattern simply assigns a new, unused owner object to the Kid factory (to pass validations). Since Parent has_many Kids and Kid can have many Parents, there is no conflict when calling either factory. In your specs, you can override the default associations to test the desired behavior.

Pragmatically, you could also just not create a factory for one of these models if one of them isn't tested very much; you'd have to create "new" instances of the model for each spec, which isn't ideal if that is a common occurrence.

Hope that helps somebody!

Answer (score 0):

The answer from the page that you posted is actually quite good, so I cite it here.

You actually cannot do that. And the suggestion to use hooks is also limited.

> If you need to build object hierarchies where the objects have
>   validation rules against each other, you'll run into this inverse_of
>   issue with belongs_to associations.
>
> ActiveRecord generally will be able to save an object hierarchy
>   correctly if it's constructed entirely in memory and then saved via
>   the topmost ancestor. You can simulate this behavior in some cases by
>   using Factory.build and adding after_build hooks inside the Factory
>   definition to set up dependent objects. This does not work well for
>   more than one level of hierarchy.
>
> The last resort is to set up your own helper methods and construct
>   object hierarchies in memory, assign the dependencies, then call save
>   on the topmost parent. It's not as elegant as the Factory invocation,
>   but it can help to de-clutter a bunch of setup code to
>   work around Factory and ActiveRecord quirks.

Comment: Thanks @Elyasin, but IMO those solutions would have created more hassle than they were worth. I posted my solution, but I'd love to see what code you would have used.